# how to use django objects in views

Tags: python, django

my intent is every time a sms is sent to my server the server should look thru the database to see if the number from the sms is already a stored  object if it isn't then create and save the object to the database what am i doing wrong?

views.py

```
from django.http import request
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view
from django_twilio.request import decompose
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from .models import Contacts

@twilio_view
def sms_choice(request):
    twilio_request = decompose(request)
    contact_num = twilio_request.from_
    contact_info = ['Thanks for your subscription', 
                    "How old are you?", "Annual Income?"]
    response = twilio_request.body
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    subscribers = [Contacts.objects.all()]
    for contact in subscribers:
        if contact_num != contact.customer_number:
            b = Contacts(customer_number=contact_num)
            b.save()
            resp.message(contact_info[0])
        elif contact_num == contact.customer_number:
            resp.message(contact_info[1])

    print(contact_num, response)
    return str(resp)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Contacts (models.Model):
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    customer_age = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                                    null=True)
    customer_income = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                       null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.customer_number
```

Comment: You don't seem to have described what is happening or how that differs from what you expect.

Comment: when i test the code it just creates a new class instance instead of finding it in the d.b.

Comment: But that's what you've told it to do. What do you actually want to happen?

Comment: what im try in trying to do is if the number is already store and recived the first of the contact_info questions the server should should reply with the second question

Comment: (Also note, this cannot be your actual code, because `subscribers` as you have it here is a list containing a queryset; iterating over it would not  work. Please always post actual code.)

Comment: OK, if that's what you want it to do, why do you create and save a new Contacts object? Just remove that bit of the code.

Comment: because with my service i can only contact those numbers who allow me and the way they give  me permission is by their initial sms reply which would create the initial class instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have two cases: in the first case, the contact number does not exist in your database, so you want to reply with message 1; in the second case, the contact number does exist, so you want to reply with message 2.

So, you should check to see if there is a record with that number, and if not, create it. There is a shortcut for exactly this: `get_or_create`.

```
resp = MessagingResponse()
contact, created = Contacts.objects.get_or_create(customer_number=contact_num)
if created:
    resp.message(contact_info[0])
else:
    resp.message(contact_info[1])
    # I presume you want to update the customer age here
    contact.age = response
    contact.save()
return resp
```